# How to delineate a zone of slope break

Tags: dem, analysis, slope

I have a DEM of a region and want to delineate about a half-mile region at the base of hills (e.g. an area where the slope changes from steep to shallow). I ran the slope analysis tool and it kinda works if I classify it with low slope values (0-10) and high (10+) (see image), but I am still left with the tops of ridges and high elevation areas also showing shallow slope. How might I just show a region at the base of hills? [image: Slope from DEM]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Perhaps a [topographic classification](http://www.jennessent.com/downloads/tpi-poster-tnc_18x22.pdf) might be what you are looking for. If using ArcGIS, have a look at @tom-dilts [Topography Tools](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b13b3b40fa3c43d4a23a1a09c5fe96b9)

Comment: The problematic part of this question is addressed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79490.  Follow this by masking the "toe slope" regions with a half-mile buffer outside the hills.